# How to limit access to web site deployed to Amazon Web Services?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a web site (frontend Vue application and backend NodeJS) for a client and I want to upload it to AWS for the client to see it in action.

However, I do not want the website to be visible to the public yet who may either go to the yet-to-be-marketed domain name, or accidentally stumble upon it.

Besides adding a password box to the web server itself, is there an AWS-specific way to accomplish this? Also, if I serve the frontend directly from S3, then adding a password block to the webserver won't help either. How can I limit access to the S3 frontend in that case?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to restrict access to the http port from specific IPs only. This can be controlled by the inbound rules on your security group assigned to the instance running.

I'll have to read around a little, but I don't think that you can restrict web-access to S3 hosted webpages. At best, you can define IAM roles which govern access to the content; but if the bucket is configured to serve as a static website, you can't control restrictive access.